# How to set has-navbar-fixed-top property only on some elements in Vue using Bulma?

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, bulma

I have a custom navigation bar made with Bulma and I am using Nuxt.js for creating my application. The problem is that I want to have navbar fixed on top but **only on some** of my views. For example, I want to have navigation on my index page and all of the other pages connected to the index, but I don't want to have it on my log-in and registration pages.

In Bulma docs it says:

> Add the corresponding `has-navbar-fixed-top` or `has-navbar-fixed-bottom` modifier to either `<html>` or `<body>` element to provide the appropriate padding to the page

If I do that in my app.html file all of my views will have padding on top. Is there a way to overwrite `has-navbar-fixed-top` property to unset it on views that don't need it? Or can I somehow only set it for the components/pages that should have it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is make an array full of your paths (pagesWithNavBar) and  a computed method (shouldHaveNavBar) that returns true or false based on if the current path in url matches any item from our array (pagesWithNavBar) and finally add a check in the head method that checks if we currently are on the page with path included in our array!

**.vue file - most likely your layout -> script tag**

```
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        pagesWithNavBar: [
          "/login", "/signup" // add here all your paths where u wish to have your navbar
        ] 
      } 
    },
    computed: {
      shouldHaveNavBar() {
        return this.pagesWithNavBar.includes(this.$route.path)
      }
    },
    head() { // since nuxt.js uses vue-meta to update the document head and meta attributes 
             // you can also use it for your own good which means adding meta tags or editing
             // the attributes of a body tag! you can learn more here
             // https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views/#html-head
             // or here
             // https://github.com/declandewet/vue-meta#recognized-metainfo-properties
      return { 
        bodyAttrs: { 
          class: this.shouldHaveNavBar ? "has-navbar-fixed-top" : ""
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you! I solved the problem using dom manipulation where I was removing/adding this class. But your solution is much more cleaner than mine.

Comment: Honestly I don't know how you managed to make it work but I just tested it and I don't know if I missed something but it just didn't work! So I updated my answer with a solution that works and I think it may even be better.

Comment: Does this solution work also without using Nuxt? Client side Vue javascript only.

Comment: This solutions is taking advantage of vue-meta which comes with Nuxt. If you want to use this code in your application you would have to install [vue-meta](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/). If you don't want to get vue-meta then you have to find another solution.